# Air printing a view

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, airprint

im using xcode 5.
I would like to know how to air print the current view. So a simple button that says "print" then when the user taps on it, it prints everything on the screen. How would i implement this?

Answer (score 2):

Take screenshot of the view

and save as png in the path and pass the data to UIPrintInteractionController

SCREENSHOT

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.frame.size, NO, 0.0);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

CGRect rect=self.view.frame;


CGImageRef cropped1 = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(viewImage.CGImage, rect);
UIImage *imges =  [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cropped1]; 
CGImageRelease(cropped1);
// squarecropimg.image=imges;

NSData *date=UIImagePNGRepresentation(imges);
NSArray *paths=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *doc=[paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *appstr=[doc stringByAppendingPathComponent:@“currentview.png"];
```

[date writeToFile:appstr atomically:YES];

Pass the Data of CURRENTVIEW.PNG to the printer

Comment: FYI: YOU NO need to Write the image on the path untill it requires. YOu can just pass the data from the UIImagePNGRepresentation and pass to air print

Comment: Thanks, but do I add anything in the .h file? Sorry, im really new to xcode development @Parthi

Comment: No need to add any in file.

Answer (score 0):

FOR integrating UIPrintInteraction add UIPrintInteractionControllerDelegate and use the below code

```
UIPrintInteractionController *print_picker = [UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];

if(print_picker && [UIPrintInteractionController canPrintData: **CURRENTIMAGE DATA HERE** ] ) {

    print_picker.delegate = self;

    UIPrintInfo *printInfo = [UIPrintInfo printInfo];
    printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputGeneral;
    printInfo.jobName = @"JOBNAME";
    printInfo.duplex = UIPrintInfoDuplexLongEdge;
    print_picker.printInfo = printInfo;
    print_picker.showsPageRange = YES;
    print_picker.printingItem = **CURRENTIMAGE DATA HERE**;

    void (^completionHandler)(UIPrintInteractionController *, BOOL, NSError *) = ^(UIPrintInteractionController *pic, BOOL completed, NSError *error) {
        //self.content = nil;
        if (!completed && error) {
            NSLog(@"FAILED! due to error in domain %@ with error code %u", error.domain, error.code);
        } 
    };

    [print_picker presentAnimated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];

}
```

Comment: I am so sorry for bothering and annoying you, but what am I meant to put in **CURRENTIMAGE DATA HERE** and in [self getimagedate]; I am getting errors for only these two. Thank you again

Comment: You need to put See first code for screenshot NSData *date=UIImagePNGRepresentation(imges);

this date in both CURRENTIMAGE DATA. I have edited my above answer